# insert Custom metrics to elastic stack and the use them in observability

Tags: elastic-stack, metrics, zabbix, elk

We want to dump the items collected in zabbix to elastic stack as metrics and then use them to create rules and dashboards by applying aggregation on that data .
Is there any way to do that .